# BackAndroid does not quit application

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am using `BackAndroid` in react-native android. It works fine when I move to next page from home page and back to home page but after if i press back it does not quit application.

Here is my code:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    let context = this
    if (Platform.OS !== 'ios') {
        BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', context.backAndroidHandler);
    }
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    let context = this
    var Meteor = context.props.value.DDPClient;

    // TODO Unsuscribe is not a valid function
    Meteor.unsuscribe(subscriptionId);
    context.props.value.setCurrentConversationID(null);

    if (Platform.OS !== 'ios') {
        BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', context.backAndroidHandler);
      }      
  },

  backAndroidHandler: function(){
      // console.log('hardwareBackPress');
      this.props.navigator.pop();
      return true;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying that the button should pop() whatever the stack view is. What you can do in your `backAndroidHandler` is :

```
if (this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
  this.props.navigator.pop();
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still quits the application, I want it to be on the previous page

Comment: The issue is because the app is NOT QUITTING when pressing back or QUITTING when pressing back ? In my example, your app will pop up views until there is nothing left to pop, where it will quit the app.

Comment: I tried this with navigator too and the previous page is not the end page. there is one more page after this. the length in the console i am getting is 2 that is 2 objects